# Posix semaphores with FIFO not working properly

Tags: c, linux, posix, fifo

i've written a small client-server demo program that should implement a simple comunication between two process using a FIFO and two semaphores.
The problem is that even if i've put a sem_wait before the client reads the fifo, he dosen't wait for the server to write on the fifo so the client reads the old value ("2" instead of "pippo"). I really can't find where the mistake is. Following the code of Server and Client.
I hope someone could help me.

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>   
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define FIFO_FILE "MIA_FIFO"

FILE * fiforw ; 

int fifo_write ( char * buf );  
int fifo_read ( char * buf );

sem_t *pizz;
sem_t *cli;

int main(void){

fiforw=fopen ( FIFO_FILE, "rw");

pizz=sem_open("pizz",  O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
cli=sem_open("cli",  O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);

char buff[20];
int pieces=10;;

sprintf(buff,"%d",pieces);

fifo_write(buff);

sem_post(cli);

sem_wait(pizz);

fifo_read(buff);

printf("I've read %s \n",buff);  //here he should read "pippo" instead of "2"


fclose ( fiforw );

}

int fifo_write ( char * buf ) {

    fputs ( buf, fiforw );

    return 1;
}

int fifo_read ( char * buf ) {

    fgets( buf, sizeof(buf)+1, fiforw);

    return 1;
}
```

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>   
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define FIFO_FILE "MIA_FIFO"

int fifo_write ( char * buf );  
int fifo_read ( char * buf );

sem_t *pizz;
sem_t *cli;
FILE * fiforw;

int main(void){

    mkfifo(FIFO_FILE,0666);
    fiforw = fopen ( FIFO_FILE, "rw");  

    char buff[20];
    char temp[]="pippo";
    pizz = sem_open("pizz", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    cli= sem_open("cli", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);

    //while(1) {

    sem_wait(cli);

    fifo_read(buff);

    printf("the value is %s \n",buff);  

    sprintf(buff,"%s",temp);    

    printf("i will write pippo on the fifo \n");

    fifo_write(buff);

    sem_post(pizz);

    fclose ( fiforw );
    //}

}


int fifo_write ( char * buf ) {
    fputs ( buf, fiforw );
    return 1;
}

int fifo_read ( char * buf ) {
    fgets( buf, sizeof(buf)+1, fiforw);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Start by adding error checking and handling - what happens if `sem_open()` or another function fails?

Comment: And you're trying to open a fifo in read-write mode? That's... interesting, since they're one-way pipes. I don't even know what that would look like.

Comment: Apparently that was the problem. But opening it with: fiforw=open(fifo_file,O_RDWR) works flawlessly. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Running server first then client is required. If that is the case, it can be helpful to check return codes from system calls.

Comment: Yes i've did this. The program crash when the server is writing on the fifo. But if i open the fifo with open(FIFO_FILE,O_RDWR) it works